# How to JOIN four tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables `orders`, `items`, `projects`, and `stores`. I would like to join them together.

This is my `orders` table:

[image: this is My Orders Table with.]

My expected result will look like this:

[image: my expected result will look like this:]

Also this is my naked query without join.

```
SELECT orders.ID,orders.Quantity, items.Desc, stores.store_name, projects.Project_no
FROM orders, items, stores, projects
```

Comment: post sample data for other tables also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ID columns are named the same in the other tables,

```
SELECT orders.ID, orders.Quantity, items.Desc, stores.store_name, projects.Project_no 
FROM orders
join items on items.item_id=orders.item_id
join stores on stores.store_id=orders.store_id
join projects on projects.project_id=orders.project_id
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a join on the primary keys and foreign keys of other table.

for eg.

```
SELECT orders.ID,orders.Quantity, items.Desc, stores.store_name, projects.Project_no
FROM   orders
  join items    ON (orders.orderId = items.orderid) 
  join stores   ON (items.storeID = store.storeID)
  join projects ON (projects.projectId = store.projectId)
```

Note : this is assume some primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT orders.ID,orders.Quantity, items.Desc, stores.store_name, projects.Project_no FROM orders o

inner join items on items.item_id - o.item_id
inner join stores on stores.store_id = o.store_id
inner join Projects on projects.project_id = o.project_id
```

This should work, however i have made assumptions about your id columns in your additional tables.